# Can't get textbox input converted to an integer?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

I am trying to create a program that takes a user input number and compares it to a randomly generated number until the user guesses the correct number. I was having a problem where my user input number is showing up undefined while I am debugging my program but I used parseInt and fixed the issue. Now it seems it is an issue with my if else statement because I get the right use input number back now when I run a debug on my code but it now when I run it, even when I enter 1000 as my guess, it always gives me "Your guess is too low! Try a higher number."

```
var guessNum;//user input guess


function randomNumber(guessNum1)
{

    guessNum = document.getElementById( "numInput" ).value;//getting value of user input
    var guessNum1 = parseInt(guessNum);//change user input to integer
    
    var num = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 1000 ); //random number generator 
    
    if (num == guessNum1)
    {
        messages.innerHTML = "Congratulations! You guessed the number!";
    
    }
        else if (num < guessNum1)
        {
            messages.innerHTML = "Your guess is too high! Try a lower number.";
        }
            else (num > guessNum1)
            {
                messages.innerHTML = "Your guess is too low! Try a higher number.";
            }
    
    guessNum = document.getElementById( "numInput" ).value = "";//clears the textbox on screen
            
}

function start()
{
    var guessButton = document.getElementById( "guess" );//variable for clicking button
    guessButton.addEventListener( "click", randomNumber, false);
    //event listener for button that starts randomNumber function
    messages = document.getElementById( "messages" );
}

window.addEventListener( "load", start, false);//starts start function on screen load
```

```
<h1>Guess the Number!</h1>

<h3>Enter in a number between 1-1000 in the textbox and hit submit </h3>

<form action = "#">
    <input id= "numInput" type="text" >
    <input id= "guess" type="button" value="Guess" > 
</form>

<p id= "messages">Enter a number to start the game </p>
```

Comment: Did you tried with ParseInt ?

Comment: @Anton I just changed  var guessNum1 = guessNum.valueAsNumber; to use parseInt instead and now I get back the right number I input but it is still not running through my if else statement. It always goes straight to the else part of " Your guess is too low! Try a higher number"

Comment: Your code is going to generate a new random number every time they try and guess. You can not keep calling `var num = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 1000 );`

Comment: @epascarello i took it out of my function but that didn't fix the issue with my if else statement

Comment: `} else(num > guessNum1) {` is not valid. else does not have a condition.